# Can I change folder of built files using angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When building an application with angular-cli, it creates a dist folder with four bundled files (`polyfills.bundle.js`, `main.bundle.js`, `vendor.bundle.js` and `inline.bundle.js`) in its root.

Is it possible to indicate another folder ONLY for these files (e.g. `dist/deps/` instead of `dist/`)?

Comment: Read the docs: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks but I couldn't find an answer to my question!

Comment: The answer is still in the docs, it's just: no. You may be able to `ng eject` to get enough control of the config, but you can't do what you describe within the options the CLI exposes.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the output directory from 'dist' to somewhere else, you can do so by changing `outDir` in the `.angular-cli.json`

```
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist/deps",
```

Comment: outDir will put everything in the folder... I want ONLY the bundled files (the 4 files I mention in my question)